# How can I get Persian date?

Tags: calendar

If I open `calendar` and hit `p p` it shows me —by calling `(calendar-persian-print-date)`— the Persian date in minibuffer. How can I get Persian date without opening `calendar`? When I call `(calendar-persian-print-date)` directly, it says `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable displayed-month)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `C-h f` (`describe-function`)'s "completion" feature to discover function that you don't know yet, e.g., enter `calendar-persian` in the minibuffer then type `TAB`, it will show all functions with that prefix.

```
(calendar-persian-date-string)
     => "Xordad 10, 1396"

(calendar-persian-from-absolute
 (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian
  (calendar-current-date)))
     => (3 10 1396)
```